# discord.js: How do I replace reactions with buttons in my ticket system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am developing my ticketing system in the last time. I saw an update of 'Ticketsbot' and turned curious "how is that possible???, i have never seen that!"
[image: this]
So, can you please help me how can I replace reactions with such buttons.

The part of my code (part which is responsible for reactions):

```
let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(`Welcome to your ticket!`)
    .addField('Here you can:', ':one: Report an issue or bug of the server.\n:two: Suggest any idea for the server.\n:three: Report a staff member of the server.')
    .addField('Make sure to be patient, support will be with you shortly.', `<@&837064899322052628>`)
    .setColor('#468DFF')
    .setFooter(`AftNetwork`)

let embed2 = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(`React with ⛔ if your issue has been resolved.`)
    .setColor('#468DFF')
    .setFooter(`AftNetwork`)

let reactionMessage = null;
try {
  reactionMessage = await channel.send(`${message.author}`, {
embed: embed,
}).then(message => message.channel.send(embed2));
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  return message.channel.send(
    '⚠️ Error sending message in ticket channel!',
  );
}

try {
  await reactionMessage.react('');
  await reactionMessage.react('⛔');
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return channel.send('⚠️ Error sending emojis!');
}

const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector(
  (reaction, user) => {
    // collect only reactions from the original
    // author and users w/ admin permissions
    const isOriginalAuthor = message.author.id === user.id;
    const isAdmin = message.guild.members.cache
      .find((member) => member.id === user.id)
      .hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES');

    return isOriginalAuthor || isAdmin;
  },
  { dispose: true },
);

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
    // lock: admins only
    case '':
      const isAdmin = message.guild.members.cache
        .find((member) => member.id === user.id)
        .hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES');

      if (isAdmin) {
        channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
          SEND_MESSAGES: false,
        });
      } else {
        // if not an admin, just remove the reaction
        // like nothing's happened
        reaction.users.remove(user);
      }
      break;
    // close: anyone i.e. any admin and the member
    // created the ticket
    case '⛔':
      channel.send('Deleting this ticket in 5 seconds...');
      setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
      break;
  }
});
```

Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now there is no official wrapper so [here](https://discord-buttons.js.org/) is an unofficial library that you can use and also here is a small exemple. You can join their discord on the link provided for more help.

```
let button = new MessageButton()
.setLabel("I like")
.setStyle("blurple")
.setEmoji("")
.setID("like_button")
```

what you will add is the above code and in the `.send()` funtion it will be this `` channel.send(`${message.author}`, {embed: embed, component: button}) ``
and that's basically it.

Comment: thank you, but error: (node:800) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: animated is not defined
    at MessageButton.setEmoji (/home/runner/aftbot/node_modules/discord-buttons/src/v12/Classes/MessageButton.js:67:9)

Comment: @Papacito can you provide the code you used?

Comment: it is too long.

Comment: can we continue in discord?

Comment: @Papacito sure Gruz#4639